# How to convert time into numbers?

Tags: time, netlogo

I am modelling a production scheduling based on the actual operations data. The data provide me the shift schedule as show below:

```
shift_start shift_end
0:10    4:00
4:00    6:00
8:00    11:00
11:00   13:30
13:30   17:00
18:30   23:30
```

or another format as:

```
shift_start shift_end
0100    0400
0400    0600
0800    1100
1100    1330
1330    1700
1830    2330
```

however, both of these are not a good format to be read from netlogo ticks function. How to automatically change the time format into numbers like below:

```
shift_start shift_end
10     240
240    360
480    660
660    810
810    1020
1110   1410
```

or is there built-in function in netlogo that supports time reading?

The whole dataset looks like below, (item 5 is the shift start time, item 6 is the end time)
I am reading the whole set with csv extension method

```
028W    028W0410    IB  0   1   250 360 0.48    2.78    14.98
028W    028W0800    IB  0   1   480 660 0.54    3.1 18.43
028W    028W1200    IB&OB   0.5 0.5 720 870 0.51    2.58    13.89
028W    028W1430    IB&OB   0.5 0.5 871 910 0.39    2.54    14.83
028W    028W1830    OB  1   0   1110    1410    0.44    2.08    18.08
028W    028W2331    IB&OB   0.5 0.5 1411    240 0.47    2.42    20.25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to convert to the number of hours, this should work as long as your data is consistently formatted in the way you've indicated. I'm assuming your values are being read in as string values:

```
globals [ shift-start shift-end ]

to setup
  ca
  set shift-start [ "0:10" "4:00" "8:00"  "11:00" "13:30" "18:30" ]
  set shift-end   [ "4:00" "6:00" "11:00" "13:30" "17:00" "23:30" ]
  show map convert-to-n-minutes shift-start
  show map convert-to-n-minutes shift-end
  reset-ticks
end


to-report convert-to-n-minutes [ string ]
  let ind position ":" string
  let sub1 read-from-string substring string 0 ind
  let sub2 read-from-string substring string ( ind + 1) ( length string )
  report ( sub1 * 60 ) + sub2 
end
```

Output:

```
observer: [10 240 480 660 810 1110]
observer: [240 360 660 810 1020 1410]
```

Note that this will not accommodate any shifts that start on one day and end on the next.

**Edit:** You should be able to accommodate the format as needed, so long as you are consistent. This modified version will read either "00:00" or "0000" format. Note that your values `"0100"` and `"0:10"` indicate 1 hour and 10 minutes respectively.

```
to setup
  ca  
  let shift-original [ "0:10" "4:00" "8:00"  "11:00" "13:30" "18:30" ]
  let shift-new [ "0100" "0400" "0800" "1100" "1330" "1830" ]
  show word "Original:" shift-original
  show word "Parsed:  " ( map convert-to-n-minutes shift-original ) 
  print ""
  show word "New:    " shift-new
  show word "Parsed: " map convert-to-n-minutes shift-new

  reset-ticks
end


to-report convert-to-n-minutes [ string ]
  let ind position ":" string
  let sub1 0
  let sub2 0
  ifelse ind != false [
    set sub1 read-from-string substring string 0 ind
    set sub2 read-from-string substring string ( ind + 1) ( length string )
  ] [
    set sub1 read-from-string substring string 0 2
    set sub2 read-from-string substring string 2 4
  ]
  report ( sub1 * 60 ) + sub2
end
```

Output:

```
observer: "Original:[0:10 4:00 8:00 11:00 13:30 18:30]"
observer: "Parsed:  [10 240 480 660 810 1110]"

observer: "New:    [0100 0400 0800 1100 1330 1830]"
observer: "Parsed: [60 240 480 660 810 1110]"
```

**Edit 2:**

Assuming a dataset like the one you have shown in your edited question:

```
extensions [ csv ]

globals [ shift-start shift-end ]

to setup
  ca
  let data csv:from-file "data/timesheet.csv"
  set shift-start map [ i -> add-zero ( word item 5 i ) ] data
  set shift-end map [ i -> add-zero ( word item 6 i ) ] data
  print map convert-to-n-minutes shift-start
  print map convert-to-n-minutes shift-end
  reset-ticks
end


to-report convert-to-n-minutes [ string ]
  let ind position ":" string
  let sub1 0
  let sub2 0
  ifelse ind != false [
    set sub1 read-from-string substring string 0 ind
    set sub2 read-from-string substring string ( ind + 1) ( length string )
  ] [
    set sub1 read-from-string substring string 0 2
    set sub2 read-from-string substring string 2 4
  ]
  report ( sub1 * 60 ) + sub2
end

to-report add-zero [ string ]
  if length string >= 4 [
    report string
  ]
  report add-zero insert-item 0 string "0"  
end
```

Output:

```
[170 320 440 551 670 851]
[240 420 550 550 850 160]
```

However, again this relies on consistency in your dataset.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found that the time data from the system has another format (see my edited). is this ok to convert?

Comment: @Jack - It should be fine with the modified reporter in the edits above, as long as it's read in as a string.

Comment: 1). How to make Netlogo read the number as a string? I am reading all the data using csv extension (see my source data format in above edited).  2). can you keep the earlier solution as I need it as well.

Comment: @Jack - Have a look at one option in the second edit to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a time extension to NetLogo that does exactly what you want-- among other things it creates a new NetLogo time variable type that is an exact date and time, plus a number of primitives for manipulating and comparing times. And it includes discrete event scheduling: you can program your agents to schedule actions at future times.

The problem is that the time extension is still being updated and tested for inclusion in a future version of NetLogo. Some parts of it are not debugged yet. Be sure to look at the "issues" to see what we know is not working.

The original version is here:
https://github.com/colinsheppard/time
but its discrete event simulation does not work in new versions of NetLogo.

The development version is here:
https://github.com/NetLogo/Time-Extension